# How does a so-called "LED monitor" work?

Tags: display, lcd

Every here and there I hear about *new LED monitors*. I imagined that they were really LED monitors - that their screens were formed of multiple tiny LEDs that lit up in a controlled manner to form an image. Yet [turns out](http://www.lg.com/uk/it-products/monitors/led-monitor.jsp) they are *LED backlit LCD monitors*.

What's the difference between this and a trusty Belinea 10 17 51 I've been using for the five years already?

Comment: Note that although "LED monitors" are not what you once imagined them to be, "OLED monitors" are actually exactly that: millions of tiny (organic, hence the "O") LEDs forming subpixels of the screen. Yes, marketing is confusing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a more in-depth explanation:

You got the concept wrong when you imagined it to be millions of LEDs flashing the different hues of colors to give you a display - all these kind of monitors are made of invariably 2 layers - a front layer of LCD (Liquid Crystal Display or Liquid Crystal Diode) that makes up the dots you see as pixels, along with the display of color.

[image]

This LCD layer is then back-lighted using light tubes at the back, giving it brightness. Formerly, LCD displays use to use CCFL (Cold Cathode Flourescent Lamp) as a light source at the back, but however in recent years there has been a marked shift towards the use of LED (Light Emitting Diode) as a back-light source. The advantages of LEDs are as follows:

1. **Faster Turn On**: LEDs can reach
   maximum brightness faster than
   CCFLs, in fact almost instantly.
2. **More Neutral Colors**: CCFLs are known
   to give a warm/yellowish tint. LEDs
   have a more neutral whitepoint.
3. **Brighter**: LEDs are brighter
   generally than CCFLs, thus allowing
   a display to achieve even higher
   maximum brightness.
4. **Thinner**: The
   reason LEDs are coming into
   prominence is that it was driven by
   the notebook sectors - LED
   back-lighting can be made thinner
   than CCFL back-lighting.
5. **Longer-Lasting**: Apparently, LEDs are
   rated for more life than CCFLs. Also
   the degradation over time is less
   severe than CCFLs.

Well, these are the primary reasons why LED-based LCDs are considered to be better than CCFLs. They still come with a price premium though.

Comment: LEDs have a lifetime longer than my house...

Comment: LED screens also potentially use less electricity and deeper blacks than CCFL backlit screens.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the blacks on an LED screen are blacker too since portions of the backlight can be turned off when black is needed.  A normal LCD, tun the crystal opaque to stop the light coming through.  No backlight = better black.

\\Greg

Answer (score 1):

The backlight uses less energy and generates less heat then fluorescent backlights.

Comment: Emmm... Do you imply that pre-"LED" monitors had fluorescent backlights? That sounds insane. How can a fluorescent lamp be durable enough?

Comment: O_o Where are you located that has glass which shatters when touched...

Comment: I see there is irony in your comment but I'm not a native English speaker and just don't get it. Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: I've seen this too. The back light is a fluorescent light at the bottom of the screen and a special kind of plastic is used to evenly distribute the light to the entire screen. You can see this at the bottom of the page here: http://www.laptoprepair101.com/laptop/2007/12/09/replace-laptop-backlight-ccfl-lamp/

Comment: @James: I see now. Didn't know they have a special kind of fluorescent lamps suitable for display backlights.